# pass array or slice into go-elasticsearch search query

Tags: go, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I need to pass array or slice in my go-elasticsearch query for search.
for example:

```
filters := make([]json.RawMessage, 0)
channelids := []string{"2", "3", "4"}
termFilter, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{"term": map[string]interface{}{"channelids": channelids}})
filters = append(filters, termFilter)
termFilter1, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{"term": map[string]interface{}{"user": "kimchy"}})
filters = append(filters, termFilter1)

query, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{
        "query": map[string]interface{}{
            "bool": map[string]interface{}{
                "must": filters,
            },
        },
    })
```

`querybody1: {"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"channelids":["2","3","4"]}},{"term":{"user":"kimchy"}}]}}}`

when I pass this query it through error:

```
    {
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "x_content_parse_exception",
        "reason" : "[1:49] [bool] failed to parse field [must]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "x_content_parse_exception",
    "reason" : "[1:49] [bool] failed to parse field [must]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "illegal_state_exception",
      "reason" : "Can't get text on a START_ARRAY at 1:49"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

According to my findings it is due to `{"channelids":["2","3","4"]}}` in `querybody1`.
So,How can I manage it? or pass array in search query.

Comment: Can you share the api endpoint? What type of body is expected?

Comment: `var buf bytes.Buffer
 if err := json.NewEncoder(&buf).Encode(query); err != nil {
  
fmt.Println("################ err: ", err)
 
}`
`res, err = es.Search(
  es.Search.WithContext(context.Background()),
  es.Search.WithIndex("manzoor-local-post-index"),

  es.Search.WithBody(&buf),
  es.Search.WithTrackTotalHits(true),
  es.Search.WithFrom(page),
  es.Search.WithSize(100),
  es.Search.WithPretty(),
 )`


here is api endpoint.